# Protect a cell from public reading

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to prevent reading for public users - of a specific cell.
The cell contains a web api key, which is used in some Formulas to get content from a web api.

So far I see I can protect a cell from being edited, but how can I hide the content?
The only way I found, I was able to add a script and in the script the key is specified. But I would really like to have the key in the document itself.

Or is there some other mechanic to insert "hidden" data or password protected data?

Comment: Hide the row with the formula?

Comment: Hm well yes, that should work. But then when someone copies my sheet, he will get access to that. So yes if public but copy disabled that would work.

Comment: You can prevent viewers from downloading the sheet

Comment: Yes, but that is just the reason I wanted it to be "protected". So people can copy the sheet, but have to enter there own key.

Comment: Have a  public view only sheet for public ad. In the public sheet,Link to a template sheet for download,which doesn't have a webapi key.

Comment: Another way to do this is via `IMPORTRANGE()`,which will only access the public sheets values(So,Formulas containing webapi will remain unexposed). But, I don't know the exact nature of your template. Hence i'm not sure how this will work for you.

Comment: `=IMAGE(ImportJSONViaPost("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamRemoteStorage/GetPublishedFileDetails/v1?",CONCATENATE("itemcount=1&publishedfileids[0]=",B2),"","/response/publishedfiledetails/preview_url","noTruncatem,noHeaders"))`
Well something like that, just the key gets add in the function importJSON.

Comment: I am not sure if importrange can import image outputs. I think the best solution, as i said above, is two  spreadsheets: public(view only,non-downloadable,key hidden) and template(downloadable, no key)

Comment: Ah perfect - now I understand.
So a second sheet, and there I store private data. And with importrange I use it in another sheet. Seems I did not see the 4. comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) the solution is to use a second spreadsheet.

```
I am not sure if importrange can import image outputs. I think the best solution, as i said above, is two spreadsheets: public(view only,non-downloadable,key hidden) and template(downloadable, no key)
```